# Standard c macros to indicate length of MAC address?

Tags: c, macros, mac-address

Are there standard (or semi-standard, widely deployed) C macros for:

1. The length of a MAC address formatted as 00:11:22:33:44:55, i.e. 17 bytes.
2. The length of a raw MAC, i.e. 6 bytes.

I have seen these defined in proprietary header files at various times, but I see a lot of sample/tutorial code that otherwise uses "proper" macros and doesn't have anything for these -- the "6" is always hardcoded.

FWIW I'm on linux.

Obviously it's trivial to define my own, but I'd like to use a standard where possible.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Are you literally just looking for a macro defined to be 17 and another defined to be 6?

Comment: @Perry: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Or 18, if the macro happens to define the size of the buffer required, including the NUL terminator.

Answer (score 3):

Some platforms define a "/usr/include/net/ethernet.h" which does something like:

`#define ETHER_ADDR_LEN 6`

And some platforms have similar defines in `if_ether.h` (located in various places, including netinet).

However, I'm unaware of anything that defines the length of a "string formatted" address, and I'm unaware of any standard that imposes these `#define`s, so they're likely not universally portable.